# Seeking shapefiles of business locations

Tags: shapefile, data, point-of-interest

Does anyone know where to find shapefiles of businesses such as grocery stores or gas stations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 similar questions that contain answers that may guide you to find the Points of Interest data you are looking for:

- [Seeking GIS data for fast food industry?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/gis-data-for-fast-food-industry)
- [POI Datasets for North America](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/poi-datasets-for-north-america)

Particularly take a look at OpenStreetMap, SimpleGEO, and POI Factory.

Additionally, you should browse the questions tagged as [POI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poi), [business](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data), and [datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datasets).

Whatever dataset you choose to go with, be sure to read the Terms & Conditions to make sure you are legally able to use the data for your purposes.